# Rails REST API - Returning ID of any nested object instead of object itself

Tags: json, rest, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building a REST API using Ruby on Rails and an Angular frontend to interact with this backend. The gem [rails-api](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails-api/versions/0.4.0) is used. Thus I only play with json data in my requests, no html. See the `json:` keyword:

```
def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  render json: @article
end
```

Let's say I have 2 models:

- *Music*
- *Article*: may contain a *Music* (`belongs_to :music`)

In the previous snippet of code, a GET of an *Article* resource returns this kind of json (simplified):

```
{
  "id":2,
  "title":"A great title",
  "content":"The amazing content of my article",
  "music":{
    "id":8,
    "artist":"Pink Floyd",
    "title":"Wish You Were Here"
  }
}
```

It is returning the object *Music* contained into the *Article* object. This is the default behavior of Ruby on Rails. But I always heard that proper REST API should return the location of the nested resource instead of the resource itself. I would like to follow this golden rule by returning the id of the music present in the article.

**What I want is** to return the id of the music instead of the whole object, so the json response would look like this:

```
{
  "id":2,
  "title":"A great title",
  "content":"The amazing content of my article",
  "music":8
}
```

I was expecting to find in the documentation an option to add somewhere in order to activate this behavior, or at least a post about an homemade solution but I didn't. I'm surprised that this simple, but important (at least for me) thing is not implemented.

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior I was looking for is handled by the Serializer. Thus the solution was to specify in the corresponding serializer that I don't want the music object:

```
class ArticleSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :content, :created_at, :music
end
```

but the id of the music object (`:music_id`):

```
class ArticleSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :content, :created_at, :music_id
end
```